Windows security lost while calling a WCF from a windows scheduled task
I have simple command line application that calls a WCF service using windows security with the following binding :
<binding name="***">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
    </security>
</binding>

If I call this app via command line (using runas with the service account), everything works fine.
If I do the exact same thing from a scheduled task(with the same service account, from the same computer), I get the following exception :
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="serverhostname"'.
This is the requests in the log files
2024-05-03 18:55:24 1.1.1.1 POST /MyService.svc/WinAuth - 443 - 1.1.1.1 - - serverhostname 401 2 5 0 1.1.1.1
2024-05-03 18:55:24 1.1.1.1 POST /MyService.svc/WinAuth - 443 - 1.1.1.1 - - serverhostname 401 1 2148074252 1 1.1.1.1

I have tried pretty much every combination of the following scheduled task options :

Run only when user is logged on
Run wether user is logged or not
Do not store password
Run with highest privileges
I also tried with a user who's admin of both computers(client and
server)

Does anyone have any idea why the scheduled task does not want to send my user authentication to the server?
Additionnal info : if I use the basic auth endpoint, it does work, but to use it in the actual app (this one is only to diagnose the problem) I would have to modify a lot of shared components a test again a lot of client apps using it.
